# How to insert a unique ID into each SQLite row?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have the following SQLite code. How do I insert an auto generating unique ID into each row?

```
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ENTRIES');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENTRIES (id unique, data)');

    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ENTRIES (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ENTRIES (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could define `id` as an [auto increment column](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

```
create table entries (id integer primary key autoincrement, data)
```

As MichaelDorner notes, the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) says that an `integer primary key` does almost the same thing and is slightly faster. A column of that type is an alias for `ROWID`, which [behaves like an autoincrement column](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) with the difference that without `AUTOINCREMENT` the ID of the row might be reused. "In other words, the purpose of `AUTOINCREMENT` is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows."[[source](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html#summary)]

```
create table entries (id integer primary key, data)
```

This behavior is implicit and could catch inexperienced SQLite developers off-guard.

Comment: Notice, that "The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed." ( https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html )

Comment: @MichaelDorner: Thanks, interesting, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Note that it *has* to be `integer` and not `int` in PHP with PDO, otherwise it doesn't automatically set the id.

Comment: if you have a bunch of distinct strings that you want to store and if autoincrement has to be avoided, how would you go about it? considering that these strings will be repeated in a different time many times (foreign key situation)

Comment: The decision about using AUTOINCREMENT or not should be whether or not you want keys in a given table being reused. For instance if row with key=7 has been deleted, would you like to insert the next row using the (now available) 7 as a key? If you don't want to reuse it, then you need to go with AUTOINCREMENT

Answer (score 21):

This is the syntax that I use.

```
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
```

Simply don't provide data for the autoincrement column

```
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ENTRIES (id, data) VALUES (NULL, "First row")');
```

Or even simpler

```
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ENTRIES (data) VALUES ("First row")');
```

Answer (score 4):

`autoincrement` is your friend buddy.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENTRIES (id integer primary key autoincrement, data);
INSERT INTO ENTRIES (data) VALUES ("First row");
INSERT INTO ENTRIES (data) VALUES ("Second row");
```

and then:

```
> SELECT * FROM ENTRIES;
1|First row
2|Second row
```

Answer (score 1):

for the INSERT, better provide a "null" value for the corresponding autoincrement value's question mark placeholder.

```
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ENTRIES (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)', [null, "First row"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO WEBSITES (url) VALUES (?)', [url])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually searching for an answer to a different question, but:
https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
> disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
> usually not needed.
>
> In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit
> signed integer.
>
> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
> unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in
> use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
> keyword is used.
>
> If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the
> reuse of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the
> purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from
> previously deleted rows.

So, in other words, unless you SPECIFICALLY NEED to avoid reusing deleted IDs, the correct way to get a unique ID without the overhead of AUTOINCREMENT is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENTRIES (id integer primary key, data);
INSERT INTO ENTRIES (data) VALUES ("First row");
INSERT INTO ENTRIES (data) VALUES ("Second row");
```

Note the absence of the keyword AUTOINCREMENT in the create table statement. All of the other answers, use the keyword AUTOINCREMENT, which, according to SQLite documentation:

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead.