# Inserting rows from table2 to end of table1 with unique ids

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to add a test user to my website that employers can look at to see my work. I want to use some of the data I have entered into my profile so that it is faster.

I have a `workouts` table:

```
CREATE TABLE workouts(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    userID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DateAndTime smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

I have taken 25 of the first results and put it into a temporary `workouts2` table:

```
CREATE TABLE workouts2 (
    userid integer,
    dateandtime smalldatetime);
```

Now I want to take those rows from `workouts2` and put them into `workouts`. I have tried to add them by inserting `workouts2` into `workouts` like this:

```
insert into workouts (id , userID, DateandTime) values (select * from workouts2);
```

This gives me an `Error: in prepare, near "select": syntax error (1)`

I can do it one at a time like this:

```
insert into workouts (userid, dateandtime) values (2, "2022-01-02T06:00");
```

Doing it one at a time is not ideal.

What am I missing here? I know I have a syntax error but I don't know how to fix it.

I have looked at this question which inserts one at a time:
[How to insert a unique ID into each SQLite row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342249/how-to-insert-a-unique-id-into-each-sqlite-row)

The problem is it only inserts one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `SELECT` instead of `VALUES` and not include the column `id`, which is auto-incremented, in the list of columns of `workouts` which will receive the values (such a column does not exist in `workouts2`):

```
INSERT INTO workouts (userID, DateandTime) 
SELECT * 
FROM workouts2;
```

Comment: That's it. I guess I was focused on using VALUES too much. Why does it work if I'm only entering one row at a time?

Comment: @Funlamb because VALUES expects a list of tuples like:  `insert into workouts (userid, dateandtime) values (2, "2022-01-02T06:00"), (3, "2022-01-03T06:00"),...;`

Comment: Now I'm trying to do the same things with `sets` and `sets2`.  The problem is I have added the id's from `sets` to `sets2`. Using `INSERT INTO sets (interval, resistance, setnumber, workoutid, exerciseid) select (interval, resistance, setnumber, workoutid, exerciseid) from sets2;` gives me an error of `in prepare, row value misused (1)`. I was hoping your answer would help me for this problem too. What is going wrong here?

Comment: @Funlamb remove the parentheses from: `select (interval, resistance, setnumber, workoutid, exerciseid) from sets2`

Comment: Yeah. I just found it online. I should have looked before asking but wanted to catch you while you were still on here. Thanks for your help.